# Python: JDBC Connection Error to Apache Drill Error with JayDeBeApi

Tags: python, jdbc, apache-drill, jpype, jaydebeapi

I am trying to connect to Apache Drill from python using `jaydebeapi` library.

I have turned on drill in embedded mode via `drill-embedded`, and the web ui runs correctly in port 8047. Then, I am trying to connect via JDBC through a python script:

```
import jaydebeapi
import jpype
import os

DRILL_HOME = os.environ["DRILL_HOME"]

classpath = DRILL_HOME + "/jars/jdbc-driver/drill-jdbc-all-1.17.0.jar"
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % classpath)
conn = jaydebeapi.connect(
    'org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver',
    'jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:8047'
)
```

but I get this error

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jaydebe_drill.py", line 10, in <module>
    'jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:8047'
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 412, 
in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 230,
 in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, *dargs)
jpype._jexception.SQLNonTransientConnectionExceptionPyRaisable: 
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
Failure in connecting to Drill: oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.ChannelClosedException: 
Channel closed /127.0.0.1:62244 <--> localhost/127.0.0.1:8047.
```

Does anyone knows how to solve the issue?

Comment: (1) Are you able to connect to Drill using Java and JDBC only, i.e. without using python and JayDeBeApi?  (2) What port does Drill itself, not the web interface, use?  The documentation suggests port 2181 or 5181.  Attempting to connect a JDBC driver to a web interface on port 8047 will never work and will likely throw random networking errors such as the one you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Apparently, the problem is indeed the connection port. For `drill-embedded` there is no port to select. I'm adding an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Luke Woodward suggestion, the problem was the port. For `drill-embedded` there is no port to select. Below a full query example

```
import jaydebeapi
import jpype
import os
import pandas as pd

DRILL_HOME = os.environ["DRILL_HOME"]
classpath = DRILL_HOME + "/jars/jdbc-driver/drill-jdbc-all-1.17.0.jar"

jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % classpath)

conn = jaydebeapi.connect(
    'org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver',
    'jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost'
)

cursor = conn.cursor()

query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM dfs.`/Users/user/data.parquet`
    LIMIT 1
"""

cursor.execute(query)
columns = [c[0] for c in cursor.description]
data = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

df.head()
```